# How to realize accurate time counter (millisecond precision)

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, unity-game-engine

Sorry for my English.

I have developed a client-server game on Unity and I need equal time counters on the client and server for synchronization. On the server side (Java) all is working fine.

On the client I tried to set Fixed Time-step to 0.001 and count time on FixedUpdate. It works, but in one thread with other scripts and sometimes lags. I became convinced of this in this [article](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/the-truth-about-fixedupdate.231637/)

Also I tried to count time in other threads, but this code gets wrong time (I tried TICK_TIME 1 and 5)

```
while (started)
         {
             time += TICK_TIME;
             Thread.Sleep(TICK_TIME);
         }
```

How to realize stable counter? And is it possible in Unity?

Comment: Uhm, if the client's time needs to be synchronized with the server's time, the only way you can and should measure time on the clients is by having the server send the (authoritative) time to the clients. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_synchronization and an example here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/648861-serverclient-time-synchronization/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

//Do work

Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: It works more accurately, but with `Thread.Sleep(1)` gives 0 to 60% of cases, 1 to 30% and sometimes 2 and 3. Is there any way to get stable time?

Comment: What you are demanding is the behavior of a real-time machine/os. Thats not how it works on regular operating systems. All processes on the computer share the processors time. When you call thread.sleep(1) you basicly tell the scheduler who distributes cpu-time: "dont give me  cpu-time for the next milisecond" so when the next process on your machine takes 2ms cpu-time you will end up with 2ms thread sleep.

Comment: @Piranha Ok, I understood about Thread.Sleep(). Is there any other way? Not necessarily 1 millisecond, just the same time on clients

Comment: @kimreik What is your question specifically? Stopwatch is accurate enough, but Thread.Sleep is not. Measuring time is not the problem.

Comment: @EmilePels Yes, stopwatch accurate, thanks. Need a code that will give a stable same time on different clients.